# JavaScript to parse HTML table of numbers into an array

Tags: javascript, html-parsing, html-table

I'm parsing an existing HTML table on a webpage into an array of numbers to later pass to a plot object.  I'm learning JavaScript and it is not clear how I am supposed to iterate over the data values in HTML tags.  This is what I've come up with:

```
for (i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i += 1) {
   row = table.rows[i];
   for (j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j += 1) {
       cell = row.cells[j];
       coord[j] = Number(cell.innerText);
   }
   data[i] = coord.slice();
}
```

I'm bothered by the .innerText part.  Is that the universal mechanism for iterating over the text elements in the `<td>` tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately [`.innerText` is not universal](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04), most notably it's missing from Firefox.  Use either `.innerHTML` here if it's just text in the cell or `Number(cell.innerText || cell.textContent)` to account for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, what you are doing is fine, although `innerText` is not universally supported. Though I've got a few suggestions...

```
var coords = [],
    data = [];

for (var i = 0, rowsLength = table.rows.length; i < rowsLength; i++) {
   var row = table.rows[i];
   for (var j = 0, cellsLength = row.cells.length; j < cellsLength; j++) {
       var cell = row.cells[j];
       coord[j] = Number(cell.innerHTML);
   }
   data[i] = coord.slice();
}
```

This assumes your cell has just a number in it (or the first portion is the useful number).

- Use `var` otherwise your variables are global.
- Cache the lengths - otherwise they are calculated per iteration.
- `i++` is generally used to increment a number.