# How to convert HTML table to java array

Tags: java, html

I have Html table and I want to convert it to java array. Table looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to It looked like this in java:

num[1] = row 1, cell 1

num[2] = row 1, cell 2

num[3] = row 2, cell 1

num[4] = row 2, cell 2

How?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967874/how-to-convert-html-table-to-a-2d-array

Comment: Will it work with that format:

`<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr align= "center">
        <td align="char">TD1</td>
        <td>td1</td>
        <td align="char">TD1</td>
        <td>td1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TD2</td>
        <td>tD2</td>
        <td class="bold>Td2</td>
        <td>td2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>`